# Configuring IntelliJ IDEA with background compilation for Specs2 tests?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt

[According to the blog entry on IntelliJ Scala plugin blog](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2012/12/28/a-new-way-to-compile/), Scala compilation happens in external process.

But whenever I run Specs2 tests, it builds the whole project which takes from 1 to 3 minutes.

How to configure Specs2 tests to run correctly in IntelliJ IDEA, so it would reuse results from background thread?

Comment: I had similar experience, leading me to go running back to Eclipse Scala-IDE.  I would have tried to get community help, as you have, but having no clue as to the cause of the sluggishness, I couldn't figure out what I could write that might lead anyone to a correct diagnosis.

Answer (score 1):

I spent a long time looking into this and the fundamental problem is that IntelliJ spins up SBT for every compilation.

It was easy enough to run `sbt "~testQuick"` in a terminal window to take advantage of incremental compilation and intelligent test linking  so sbt only runs tests impacted by code changes.

http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Testing.html